# Is it possible to assign a value to an element of map using a map iterator?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I'm  reading the book *C++ Primer 5th Edition*. An exercise from it is a little bit ambiguous and  makes me confused . It goes as

> Exercise 11.16: Using a map iterator write an expression that assigns
>   a value to an element.(Page 431)

I know it can be done using `std::copy` and `std::insertor` to copy a range of elements from one container to a map. But does this exercise really imply this approach? Is it possible to do so using a map iterator rather than `std::insertor` nor insert member function?

**Update:**

This question has been narrow down to:
Is it possible to replace or add a key-value pair using a map iterator rather than `std::insertor` nor insert member function?

Comment: To me it sounds more like the task is to replace an element that is already stored in the map. Like, fetch an element using the iterator, then assign a new object, via the assignment operator the element is replaced, still accessible by the same key/iterator. Not a big deal, but that's how I would understand that phrase.

Comment: if you're asking whether you can set the *value* held in a map given an iterator resulting from a key-lookup, the answer is yes, you can, specifically via `it->second = newValue;`

Comment: @WhozCraig Thx man.I know what you mean and pretty sure your code works. But I'm not quite sure if it's what the exercise wanted.

Comment: @Alan.W it would seem to me (and ypnos) this is along the lines of what he is looking for. I'm not familiar with the latest ream of Stan's book, but I would suspect this is what he is getting at. Best of luck.

Comment: @ypnos Any element in a map is a key-value pair. Do you mean replace the value of a key-vlaue and keep the key?

Comment: @WhozCraig As a newbie of C++ and actually any programming language ,I just want to make sure there is no way to do so using a map iterator directly....

Comment: Yes Alan, my choice of words was not very good, but that's what I wanted to express.

Comment: @Alan.W While iterating on a map you cannot replace the key. It could break the map ordering.

Comment: @Johan It's what I want..but why do you guys just comment? Can anyone give me an answer? So I can accept it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `std::map<A,B>` has elements of type `std::pair<const A, B>`, not `std::pair<A,B>`. Why ?

Just to prevent you from breaking the map ordering. because a map rely on a comparator to order the elements and access them quickly. While operating on the map, the relative order of the elements have to be preserved.

Imagine that your map contains `{1, "foo"}`, `{2, "bar"}` and `{3, "foobar"}`. If while iterating you were able to replace `{1, "foo"}`  by `{4, "foo"}` the map at the end of your iteration would have to be totally rebalanced.

Not really optimal, no ?

All this text to say that I think your question is just modifying the value part of the key/value pair. You have plenty of way to do this, iterating and using `iterator->second = new_value;` is the most common.